# How can a controller know that the scope is valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm a little confused by validation in angular. All of the validation appears to be bound to the form. But what do you do in cases where the controller needs to know if the model is valid or not?

I've knocked up and example:

### HTML

```
<div  ng-app="stpApp">
<div id="multiStop" class="fullBottomContent" ng-controller="multiStopController">
<ul class="journey">
        <li ng-repeat="journey in inboundJourney">
            <ng-form name="journeyForm">
                <span>
                    <input type="text" class="AirportName" name="DepartureAirport" ng-model="journey.DepartureAirport" ng-required="true" />
                    <span ng-show="journeyForm.DepartureAirport.$error.required">Invalid</span>
            </ng-form>
            <a class="removeJourney" ng-click="removeInboundJourney($index)" href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span ng-show="valid()">this is all valid</span>
    <span ng-click="addInboundJourney()" title="Add a journey">+</span>
</div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var stpApp = angular.module('stpApp', []);

stpApp.controller('multiStopController', function ($scope, $compile, $http) {

    $scope.showAddButton = true;
    $scope.dataLoaded = false;
    $scope.inboundJourney = [
    { 'DepartureAirport': '',
        'DestinationAirport': '',
        'DepartureDate': '',
        'DepartureTime': '9',
        'Class': 'All'
    },
        { 'DepartureAirport': 'Test1',
        'DestinationAirport': '',
        'DepartureDate': '',
        'DepartureTime': '9',
        'Class': 'All'
    }
  ];

    $scope.valid = function() {
     //how do I test validity here? 
        return true;
    }
    $scope.addInboundJourney = function () {
        $scope.inboundJourney.push({ 'DepartureAirport': '',
            'DestinationAirport': '',
            'DepartureDate': '',
            'DepartureTime': 9,
            'Class': ''
        });
    }

    $scope.removeInboundJourney = function (index) {
        $scope.inboundJourney.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mbgx/)

So I want my `valid()` function to return true or false depending on whether the data in the model is valid or not. I've tried `journeyForm.$valid`, `$scope.journeyForm.$valid` and `$scope.journeyFormDepartureAirport.$valid`. None of which work.

**I can't figure out how to check `$valid` from within my controller.** Especially being as I have a variable number of forms.

Also should the controller have knowledge of the forms? That's in the view?

I think the issue is that the validation all resides within the view. I'm guessing that angular has no concept of an *invalid model*. It's just data. But, well, that's a problem for me. I want to know that the model meets all of me criteria (added into the view, such as `ng-required`) **before** I perform an action in the controller.

Comment: Ang uses 'dirty' for 'changed' models? - what are you defining as valid ? - model has data? or model has bad data , as defined by something else / schema  ??

Comment: Model has bad data, it does not validate based on my validation rules. I.e. the ng-required, in the view, has been broken

Comment: The $valid is an method on the form name="myform" . if($scope.myform.$valid) - and this relies on the form inputs having ng validation attributes set ( ng-required="true" ... ) - sorry to link and run  but this is great http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, Rob helped quite a bit actually. My problem was the placement of the form:

```
<li ng-repeat="journey in inboundJourney">
     <ng-form name="journeyForm">
```

Angular did not seem to like the form within the `ng-repeat`. I changed it to:

```
<ng-form name="journeyForm">
     <ul class="journey">
        <li ng-repeat="journey in inboundJourney">
```

i.e. the form is outside of the `ng-repeat` and then did as Rob suggested,

```
$scope.valid = function() {
    return $scope.journeyForm.$valid; /* how to return $valid for 'myform' form */
}
```

and it all worked

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mbgx/1/)

---

To moan a little this did not complain about the invalid syntax. From my limited experience of angular this is a constant issue, it's got a nasty habit of failing silently. **Needz moar error pleaz**

Comment: I just noticed in your question that you already tried **$scope.myform.$valid** - sorry for that , less haste! But yeah were right with the use. sound

Comment: No, No, @RobSedgwick, it helped. It confirmed that I wasn't going completely wrong which made me try moving the form. So it all added up!

Answer (score 1):

To explain the comment clearer on the use of `$valid`

```
<form name="myform" >
<input type="text" name="input1" ng-required="true"/>

 ....
```

JS

```
$scope.valid = function() {
        return $scope.myform.$valid; /* how to return $valid for 'myform' form */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a `$watch`

```
$scope.valid = false;

$scope.$watch('inboundJourney', function(){
    var isValid = false;
    //set isValid depending on inboundJourney
    $scope.valid = isValid;
});
```

Then set it as the show condition

```
<span ng-show="valid">this is all valid</span>
```

Comment: Cheers, @Likwid. This is another option that I may well consider.